# Is it safe to use Socket.IO in Vue.js and Laravel 5.6

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I am using Laravel 5.6, Vue.js, Socket.IO

**Below is my code to send Real Time Message using Socket.IO**

```
var url = "http://localhost:6001/apps/My_App_ID/events?auth_key=My_Key";
axios.post(url, 
    JSON.stringify(request))
        .then((response) => {
    //Message Sent
});
```

Question: Is it safe to use Socket.IO as it is client side. Anybody can see this info.

I was using Pusher as it is costly so I changed code to use Socket.IO

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io is safe, what gave you the impression it wasn't? I use it in production projects without issue.

Most often I integrate with [Laravel Echo Server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server). Broadcasting is greatly simplified and reliable with this.

You can fully secure the socket connection using HTTPS and proper authorization. There is plenty of material out there covering the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Usually your CSRF token you send with your request will be verfied on server side. Without laravel refuses any useful response, you get only kind of an error message. That is what i understood so far.